# How to hide argument names on address bar and replace them with a slash?

Tags: php

For example, I have an address like: "www.example.com/popular.php?show=comments&id=1234" and I want to show it like "www.example.com/popular/comments/1234/". What should I do?

Comment: you can use .htaccess

Comment: Or `<Directory>` block inside `httpd.conf`, if you have access to the file ([Apache.org recommendation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/htaccess.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your technology you can use `.htaccess`(apache) or `httpd.conf`(iis).

In `.htaccess` you would do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^popular/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /popular.php?show=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

What this does is is rewrite the requested url to the url with query variables.  That is, if someone types in `www.example.com/popular/comments/1234` then the server sees the url `www.example.com/popular.php?show=comments&id=1234`

The anatomy of the rewrite rule is this:

`^popular` matches any resource that begins with "/popular"
`([^/]*)` matches any thing between the 2 '/' characters, the first one is assigned to $1 and the second is assigned to $2.

Note, this does not redirect people who type in the old url to the new url. It only makes the new url function properly.

Comment: Why did you put zero or more(*) between slashes? Shouldn't you put '+' instead of '*'? And what is $1, $2 and [L]?

It didn't work. I wrote this to htaccess:

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^zirvetor/([^/]*)/ /zirvetor.php?id=$1 [L]

My url is: "localhost/zirvetor?id=9"

And I wrote it like "localhost/zirvetor/9/" and it just didn't work.

Comment: I've added some additional explanation.